# How to resolve a new error message with str_detect()?

Tags: r, stringr

To my knowledge nothing changed on my MacOS system.  But this simple execution

```
library(tidyverse)

tbb <- tibble(a = c('nn','pp'),
              b = c('zzz','yyy'))

tbb %>% 
  filter(stringr::str_detect(a,'nn'))
```

worked w/o a problem for a long time.  It now throws the error

> "Error in vctrs::vec_size_common(string = string, pattern = pattern, replacement = replacement,  :
> object 'a' not found"

I can't figure out why the new behavior is occurring. I've removed and reinstalled stringr.    Has anyone else experienced this?

What suggestions do folks have to resolve this?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the error

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of.

Comment: Try a fresh session and load only `tidyverse`.

Comment: I would suggest to just load only the required packages i.e. `library(dplyr);library(stringr)` on a fresh R  session

Comment: Done!  Same error, unfortunately.

Comment: I used `packageVersion('stringr')
[1] ‘1.5.0’` for testing.  Also, is the `filter` from `dplyr::filter`?

Comment: I don't think that error can arise from `str_detect` because that function has no `replacement = ` option. Did you use `str_replace` by mistake?

Comment: @akrun. you've asked the right question regarding filter.  When I change the statement to 
tbb %>% dplyr::filter(stringr::str_detect(a,'nn')) 

it works correctly.  

As I mentioned in my description, to my knowledge I changed nothing.    I must have updated packages such that a conflict was created.

Comment: You may have use the base filter or some other packages loaded.  Not sure

Comment: Do you happen to have library(tidyverse) in your .Rprofile? if so `stats` gets loaded after and you see its filter function and not dplyr's

Comment: @JFD have you resolved this issue? I have been facing the same issue lately as well, and I also have the same system as yourself.

Comment: @maldini1990 yes.   The solution is to use dplyr::filter().   As Sirius points out, if you have library(tidyverse) in your .Rprofile, which I do, conflicts are created.